# IDE Fatal Error: Write access is allowed from write-safe contexts only

Tags: android, intellij-idea

I have built simple Hello World application and ran it from IntelliJ on my Android device. When application starts, IDE error occur:

Write access is allowed from write-safe contexts only. Please ensure you're using invokeLater/invokeAndWait with a correct modality state (not "any"). See TransactionGuard documentation for details.

In the following window:

[image]

Simultaneously, application runs ok.

What is the reason and how to get rid of this message?

Comment: Which version of IntelliJ IDEA are you using?

Comment: Version is `2016.3.2 ULTIMATE`

Comment: Same problem. Found any solution?

Comment: Switched to `Android Studio`

Answer (score 0):

Got this same error after upgrading from a 2015 edition of IntelliJ to 2016.3.3.

After restarting the IDE, I took the suggested popup's guidance to upgrade Gradle, which then resynced and this error went away.

My project runs now and doesn't produce this error anymore.

If you are in a similar situation, I can recommend the above, as it removed this exact error in my setup.

Comment: As of 24th Jan 2017, this is an open, major issue in IntelliJ's issue tracker: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-162173